# Error With Google Webfont Not Loading Characters

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts, roboto

On my site I am using the [Google Font Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto). I noticed in several places the following:� or what I call a question mark in a black diamond. (Does this symbol have a name?)

I typically see this when a font doesn't have a character it can render, however, this doesn't appear to be the case in this instance. It happens in a few instance. One of them is when there is an extra space the other I have seen is when I use the § symbol.

I tested Roboto using the § symbol with a [type tester](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Roboto) and it works just fine.

Why doesn't it work on my site? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure why this is happening and would still love an answer but I found a solution that I am using in the mean time.

It appears to have have happened with content that was copied into my text. For spaces or other symbols were this appears (such as `-` or `/` I am just retyping the character. For the § symbol I replaced it with the HTML character `&sect;` (or you can use `&#167;`) and this has solved the issue.